# How can I load a custom attribute and display it as the default value in an input box?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, rwd-theme

Specifically, I have a custom attribute called minqty and I'd like to amend the frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml file to load this custom attribute and, if it has been set, display it in the Qty input box instead of the 1 that is currently displayed.

Here's the unedited version of the addtocart.phtml line that needs amending:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo max($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1, 1) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

nB This is for a configurable product so there is no "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" system attribute on the admin inventory tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like

```
<?php $minQty = $_product->getMinqty() ; ?>
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($minQty) ? $minQty : max($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1, 1) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```